# How can I set a text tab as read-only through the DocuSign API?

Tags: docusignapi

I am trying to add a text tab to a document within an envelope, but I want the text to remain fixed. Through the UI I can set the tab as Read-Only, which does the job.

However when creating this tab through an API request I cannot achieve the same result. According to the documentation, the 'locked' property should set the tab as read only.

However, I have used this and the tab is still created as editable by the signer.

I have included the JSON I am using to create the tab below. Is there anything I am missing, or is there something else that I need to set to achieve this?

```
{
  "tabLabel": "textTab1",
  "name": "Title",
  "anchorString": "TabTestAchorString",
  "anchorMatchWholeWord": true,
  "value": "Title Test",
  "anchorIgnoreIfNotPresent": true,
  "locked": true
}
```

Many thanks!

Answer (score 0):

**Locked** is indeed the property that makes a tab read-only
Your JSON looks correct.
Now if you still see a tab that's editable, what that means is that this tab is coming from somewhere else and your code here is not creating a tab at all.

Please include full code, or full JSON for everything you're doing.

For example, if you are using a template, then it can be the template has the tab, and your code here has no breaing.

Also, it is possible that the anchor string is not found so this code doesn't create a tab, but the tab you see is coming from some other code.

Comment: Thank you for your quick response. Following more testing, it seems as though the issue lies with the Microsoft power apps connector for DocuSign. For some reason, using this JSON did not allow me to create the tab as read-only through the connector. Creating my own custom connector allowed me to do this.

Answer (score 0):

Using a custom connector allowed me to create these tabs as Read-Only. The issue lay with the DocuSign connector in power apps.

Comment: You didn't mention this is for PowerAutomate. You are correct.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).